# Twitter Bootstrap navbar elements not aligned as desired

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and am trying to make simple menu/nav.

I am trying to make contents of the menu centered along with the brand. Also when I make the screen smaller the menu items move under the brand. How can I make it so that it doesn't? There seems to be enough space in the nav to not make the items move under.

Note: I have not written any CSS for this.

https://jsfiddle.net/b9smvjn0/

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#account-options" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <h4 class="navbar-brand">Image Box</h4>
    </div><!--end navbar header-->
    <!--togglable menu items-->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="account-options">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Upload Photo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Deactivate Account</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Activate Account</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Delete Account</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--end toggle-->
  </div><!--end container-->
</div><!--end navigation-->
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because your `h4` element inside the `navbar-header`. It's adding an extra margin on top and bottom, this is why it doesn't align.

```
.navbar-header h4 {margin:0;}
```

I removed it in your fiddle and it's working.
https://jsfiddle.net/b9smvjn0/1/

Is this what you want?

### Edit

Hopefully this is what you are looking for. 
**Note**: This is using custom css, so if you plan to stick with pure bootstrap, you'll to do in another way.

I added a div around the `brand` and the `navbar` so, we can center both elements.
Also i reduced the amount of padding on the `a` tag inside the navbar. This is necessary because of the amount of menu items you have.

Then i just used the technique of `text-align:center; margin:0 auto;` on the `container` div. It's inside a `media(min-width:768);` because when it get smaller the layout change, so we get it back to original position.

This the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b9smvjn0/3/

Comment: Part of it. How can I center all the nav content? Some menu items mover under the brand as the page gets smaller. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you able to create custom css to modify the structure? Or you want to stick with pure bootstrap? This is happening because of the amount of menu items you have. A solution would be to reduce the padding of the `a` element inside the `li` tag, or even reduce the number of menu items.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the extra space, you can remove the margin for the `<h4>`. And for centering all the `<nav>` content, or keeping it on the straight line, use these:

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oLmnjh3p/**